# How many palindromes of length 5 can be formed that contain 7 or 8?

Tags: combinatorics, palindrome

I'm trying to figure out how many palindromes of length 5 can be formed that contain 7 or 8.

My reasoning is as follows:

The pool to choose from is $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ and there are three positions that need to be filled out by these, with the exception that the number $7$ or $8$ must be used in one of the three (I assume at least once). Similarly, the first position cannot be filled by a $0$, so that leaves either the remaining options in the pool, or a $7$ or $8$. For either the second or third position, all options in the pool are available or, again, $7$ or $8$.

So, given that there are $3$ probable position that need to be filled by the required $7$ or $8$; that the first position can only be filled by $9$ options and either the second or third have $10$ options, but with one of these having being filled by the requirement, then:

$3*9*10*1 = 270$

Yet the answer is not correct. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Where the heck did the $3$ come from?

Comment: I can't see how the equation $3*9*10*1$ has anything whatsoever to do with anything that was reasoned above.

Comment: Because there $3$ possible positions for the $7$ or $8$ to assume? @fleablood

Comment: But the remaining options choices aren't the same depending upon which position you select for the 7 and the 8 and you don't take into account that there can be multiple 7s or 8s.  What you've done is so vague and messy you should scrap it entirely as start over.  It's difficult to say where you went wrong because ... there's almost nothing at all that is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of palindromes with at least an $8$ or a $7$ is the number of total palindromes minus the number of palindromes without $7$ or $8$.

To find the total number of palidromes the first terms can be anything but $0$.  That's $9$ options.  The second can be any thing.  That's $10$ options and so can the third that's $10$.  So there are $900$ possible palindromes.  (Notice that the same number of numbers between $100... 999$.  It's the exact same question.)

To find the total numbe of palindromes without $7$ or $8$ there are $7$ options for the first term.  And $8$ for the second and third.

So $7*8*8$.

So there are $900 - 7*8*8 = 452$.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: you are going wrong with just imposing a $3$ as some factor that comes in front of it. However, you are not dealing with palindromes that have multiple $7$s or $8$s.

To solve this I'll give you a hint: work out the total number of palindromes without the assumption on the 7 or 8. Afterward, you should work out the total number of palindromes containing not a $7$ and not an $8$ (which should work out similar to the first calculation). Subtract both results from each other and you have the correct result.

I hope this helps!